# Output of FuelSDK response to python dataframe

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk, python

I've been tasked with using python to pull event data from marketing cloud into a SQL database. I can get a print output with getResponse = getBounceEvent.get(), then print(getResponse.results). But the format is strange:

```
[(BounceEvent){
   Client = 
      (ClientID){
         ID = client_id_here
      }
   PartnerKey = None
   ObjectID = None
   SendID = 4016
   SubscriberKey = "subscriber_key_here"
   EventDate = 2021-05-12 12:53:38.780000
   EventType = "OtherBounce"
   TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID = None
   BatchID = 4
 }, (BounceEvent){
   Client = 
      (ClientID){
etc, etc
...]
```

I gather from the square brackets that it's ultimately a list, but what's inside it is not-quite-json. Any ideas how I can get this into a dataframe?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It seems pretty clear that I want the contents of the API result into a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by having a function that iterates over the keys and values and places them in a json object

```
def sfmc_to_json(obj=None, object_name='element'):
    """Take an object and drop it into JSON, the object_name parameter is used
        to prefex the JSON package"""
    if isinstance(obj, type({})):
        data = obj["items"]
    elif isinstance(obj, type([])):
        data = _list_of_suds_to_json(object_name, obj)
    else:
        data = _suds_to_json(obj)
    key_prefix = (object_name+"s").lower()
    return { key_prefix : data }
    #return data

def _recursive_asdict(d):
    """Convert Suds object (What API returns) into serializable format."""
    out = {}
    for k, v in _asdict(d).items():
        if hasattr(v, "__keylist__"):
            out[k] = _recursive_asdict(v)
        elif isinstance(v, type([])):
            out[k] = []
            for item in v:
                if hasattr(item, "__keylist__"):
                    out[k].append(_recursive_asdict(item))
                else:
                    out[k].append(item)
        else:
            out[k] = v
    return out
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python#example-output) states the same format. [This](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/blob/master/objsamples/sample_bounceevent.py) sample might help your use case. Extract and save the results into the list and then convert it into the pandas dataframe.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Why would you say "convert the list into a pandas dataframe" when converting the list into a pandas dataframe was the original problem?